# ¿Dónde está mi carpeta .m2 en Mac OS Sierra?

Tags: eclipse, maven

No puedo importar ningún archivo `.jar` a mi proyecto en **Eclipse**, tengo instalado `Mac OS Sierra`.

Comment: busca todos los archivos .jar a ver, concreta la versión de eclipse y el error que te da

Answer (score 1):

La carpeta `.m2` está en tu carpeta de usuario. En Mac/Linux la deberías  encontrar en:

```
~/.m2
```

Y en el caso de Windows está en:

```
C:\Users\TU_NOMBRE_DE_USUARIO\.m2
```